# find all values of x that are not in the domain of h

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

$$
h(x) = \frac{x-7}{x^2 - 3x -10}
$$

Can someone help, I need to find all values of *x* that are **not** in the domain of *h*

Comment: Can you be more specific please ,,??

Comment: Ask yourself "what does it mean for a value of x not to be in the domain of h?" After you've done that, try factoring the denominator

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem so far?  Do you have any *guesses* as to what they're looking for?

Comment: Did you see ?? you can be more speific you just define h. What else ?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Sorry ... but i haven't seen question like this I am so sorry

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Sorry but when i firstly see the question the function it was not defined. Then suddenly we see a function what can i say ? It was obvious that we missed data ....

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis there's our miscommunication.  In the earlier version, the words *"the function of h"* were blue, and if you clicked them, you saw a picture of the function.  I then fixed the question so that the function was defined on this page rather than in a linked picture.  I didn't expect that someone would miss the link.  In any case, we should probably delete our conversation, since we're cluttering up these comments.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Ok sorry again .

Answer (score 2):

The fact that this looks like a homework problem aside, consider what it means for a value of $x$ to not be in the domain of $h$. It means that $h(x)$ does not return a value. So where might this happen? Well the numerator will return a value for every $x$. So that means something has to be happening in the denominator. Recall that dividing by $0$ is impossible. So now your task becomes finding for which $x$ the denominator is equal to $0$.

Comment: I think this is what are we looking for ... When the denominator is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x-7}{x^2 -3x -10}$. To find the domain of any rational function (recognize that $f(x)$ is a rational function) we exclude those values of $x$ at which the denominator is equal to zero.

So for what values of $x$ is the denominator $x^2-3x-10$ equal to zero? This is the same as finding the values of $x$ such that $x^2-3x-10=0$. You can find the roots via the quadratic formula and factoring, or just factoring via guess and check.

Either way you will find that $f(x)=x^2-3x-10=(x+2)(x-5)$. Thus the values of $x$ at which the denominator will evaluate to zero $x=-2$ and $x=5$.

These are the two values of $x$ which we will want to exclude from the domain.

In conclusion, the domain of $f(x)$ is $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}: x \neq -2, x \neq 5 \}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** :

Write it as $$f\left( x \right) =\frac { x-7 }{ { x }^{ 2 }-3x-10 } =\frac { x-7 }{ \left( x+2 \right) \left( x-5 \right)  } \\ $$